# multiple 1.5v devices from one 9v power supply

Tags: dc, series

If I have 6 battery powered wall clocks each powered by a single AA battery, can I wire the clocks in series and connect to a 9v power supply (assuming the amperage is covered)

Answer (score 1):

No. They don't draw constant current, when they "tick" they draw several mA.

If 5 of them "tick" at the same time, there will be practically 9V across the 6th. That won't do it any good.

But more likely, when one tries to tick, the other 5 will prevent it getting enough current.

Either way ... no.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.  You might luck out and there be enough leaky capacitance to get away with it, but it's not a reliable idea.

What could work would be paralleling them on one C or D cell.

It's possible though that there could be some coupling via power draw and cell internal impedance, the really interesting question would be if this would cause them to converge, or perhaps erratically diverge.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a chain of six Zener diodes, each 1.5 V rated, and bypass each diode with a sizable electrolytic capacitor (say, 100uF to accommodate "ticks"), then a 9V supply might do the job. But it will be a lot of ugly wires around ...

Or better use two regular silicon diodes per clock, plus a small ballast resistor in series. Each "supply" in the cascade will emulate a 1.4V battery, and a 60-Ohm resistor will make something like 10 mA bias current. It might work. Something like this:

[image]